# Regex pattern generator

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to do regex pattern which will match to this:

```
Name[0]/Something
```

or

```
Name/Something
```

Verbs Name and Something will be always known. 
I did for `Name[0]/Something`,  but I want make pattern for this verb in one regex
I've tried to `sign [0]` as optional but it didn't work :

```
 var regexPattern = "Name" + @"\([\d*\]?)/" + "Something"
```

Do you know some generator where I will input some verbs and it will make pattern for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close, the regex `Name(\[\d+\])?\/Something` will do.

Comment: Your regex will match `Name[0/Something` as well

Answer (score 4):

Use this:

```
Name(\[\d+\])?\/Something
```

- `\d+` allows one or more digits
- `\[\d+\]` allows one or more digits inside `[` and `]`. So it will allow `[0]`, `[12]` etc but reject `[]`
- `(\[\d+\])?` allows digit with brackets to be present either zero times or once
- `\/` indicates a slash (only one)
- `Name` and `Something` are string literals

[Regex 101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/0yngCa/1)

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with first '\' in your pattern before '('.
Here is what you need:

```
var str = "Name[0]/Something or Name/Something";
Regex rg = new Regex(@"Name(\[\d+\])?/Something");
var matches = rg.Matches(str);
foreach(Match a in matches)
{
    Console.WriteLine(a.Value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is what you are looking for:

```
Name(\[\d+\])?\/Something
```

**Name** litteral

**([\d+])?** a number (1 or more digits) between brackets optional 1 or 0 times

**/Something** Something litteral

https://regex101.com/r/G8tIHC/1

Comment: How about more that one digit inside brackets?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov that you add a `+` right after the `d`, signifying `1 or more` of this character (number)

Comment: Yes, exactly, I think string represent index access which can be more that one digit.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var string = 'Name[0]/Something';

var regex = /^(Name)(\[\d*\])?\/Something$/;

console.log(regex.test(string));

string = 'Name/Something';

console.log(regex.test(string));
```

You've tried wrong with this pattern: `\([\d*\]?)/`

- No need to use `\` before `(` (in this case)
- `?` after `]` mean: character `]` zero or one time

So, if you want the pattern `[...]` displays zero or one time, you can try: `(\[\d*\])?`

Hope this helps!

Comment: Will the result be correct if there is not digits inside brackets?

Comment: @AndriiLitvinov Maybe wrong, but the question doesn't mention about that.